# Why won't my cross platform test automation framework run in parallel?

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, testng, cross-platform, appium

I am currently rewriting the automated testing framework for my company's mobile testing.  We are attempting to use an interface which is implemented by multiple Page Object Models dependent on the Operating System of the mobile device the application is being run on.  I can get this framework to run sequentially and even create multiple threads but it will not run in parallel no matter what I do.  Of Note, we use Appium and something called the `DeviceCart`/`DeviceConnect` which allows me to physically remote into multiple devices, thus this isn't running on a grid.  With that said I will link my pertinent code  (this is my second version of this same code, I wrote one with and one without using `ThreadLocal`)

This should instantiate a new driver with a new thread for each Test

```java
public class TLDriverFactory {

    private ThreadLocal < AppiumDriver < MobileElement >> tlDriver = new ThreadLocal <>();

    public synchronized void setTLDriver(OS platform, String server, String udid, String bundleID) {

        switch (platform) {
        case IOS:
            tlDriver = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
                try {
                    return new IOSDriver < MobileElement > (new URL(server), DesiredCapsManager.getDesiredCapabilities(OS.IOS, udid, bundleID));
                } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            });
            break;
        case ANDROID:
            tlDriver = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
                try {
                    return new AndroidDriver < MobileElement > (new URL(server), DesiredCapsManager.getDesiredCapabilities(OS.ANDROID, udid, bundleID));
                } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            });
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public synchronized ThreadLocal < AppiumDriver < MobileElement >> getTLDriver() {
        return tlDriver;
    }
}
```

This handles browser capbilities

```java
public class DesiredCapsManager {

    public static DesiredCapabilities getDesiredCapabilities(OS platform, String udid, String bundleID) {
        //Set DesiredCapabilities
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceConnectUserName", "User@Name.com");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceConnectApiKey", "API-Token-Here");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", udid);
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", platform);
        capabilities.setCapability("bundleID", bundleID);
        //IOS only Settings
        if (platform.equals(OS.IOS)) {
            capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        }
        else {
            //Android only Settings
            capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "appium");
        }

        return capabilities;
    }
}
```

This is the Base Test class from which every test inherits

```java
public class BaseTest {

    protected AppiumDriver < MobileElement > driver;
    protected AppiumSupport.TLDriverFactory TLDriverFactory = new AppiumSupport.TLDriverFactory();

    public enum OS {
        ANDROID,
        IOS
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public synchronized void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        TLDriverFactory.getTLDriver().remove();
    }
}
```

Here is the test case itself

```java
public class Test_SignIn extends BaseTest {

    protected SignInPage signInPage;

    @Parameters(value = {
        "udid",
        "bundleID",
        "platform",
        "server"
    })
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup(String udid, String bundleID, OS platform, String server) throws MalformedURLException,
    InterruptedException {
        //Set & Get ThreadLocal Driver
        TLDriverFactory.setTLDriver(platform, server, udid, bundleID);
        driver = TLDriverFactory.getTLDriver().get();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        switch (platform) {
        case IOS:
            signInPage = new SignInPageIOS(driver);
            break;

        case ANDROID:
            signInPage = new SignInPageAndroid(driver);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Current Thread ID BeforeTest: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Test
    public synchronized void Authenticate() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Current Thread ID Test 1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        signInPage.Login("Username", "Password");

    }
}
```

Here is the testng.xml file

```xml
   < !DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Test" parallel="tests" thread-count="4">
   <test name="SignIn" parallel ="instances" thread-count="2">
          <parameter name="udid" value="DeviceIdGoesHere" />
          <parameter name="bundleID" value="Environment.address.here" />
          <parameter name="platform" value="ANDROID" />
          <parameter name="server" value="http://deviceconnect/appium" />
          <classes>
              <class name="Test.Test_SignIn">
              </class>
          </classes>
   </test>
   <test name="SignIn2" parallel="instances" thread-count="2">
          <parameter name="udid" value="DeviceIdGoesHere" />
          <parameter name="bundleID" value="Environment.address.here" />
          <parameter name="platform" value="IOS" />
          <parameter name="server" value="http://deviceconnect/appium" />
          <classes>
              <class name="Test.Test_SignIn">
              </class>
          </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

What I'm looking for is if anyone can determine what mistake I've made or what the bottleneck is preventing the tests from running in parallel

Comment: How are you determining that your tests aren't running in parallel ? Have you tried printing the thread ids via `Thread.currentThread().getId()` ? I also noticed that you have a lot of `synchronized` methods. This would basically hinder parallel execution and cause sequential execution.

Comment: I actually physically see an emulator of the device screen on my monitor as well as in the console I do have thread id printed lines(inside the before method and the test).  In the realm of synchronized methods: do you have a preferred resource I can look at in order to know how to pursue that avenue to fix my issue?

Comment: I think the problem could be with your invocation of `ThreadLocal.withInitial(())` which causes a new instance of `ThreadLocal` to be created with an initial value. So you aren't creating WebDriver instances per thread, you are basically re-instantiating the `ThreadLocal` variable. Please replace that with a mere `tlDriver.set()` after you create the `IOSDriver/AndroidDriver` instance based on the platform.

Comment: For your codebase, I think you should just get rid of `synchronized` keyword and you should still be fine.

Comment: I've changed the TLDriverFactory class to remove the threadLocal usage and have removed the synchronous keyword from every method.  I also created 2 more tests in the class.  if I run the suite parallel at test level and the tests parallel at method level it instantiates threads for each method but never runs the devices in parallel.  It also doesn't actually run the tests it just opens the threads, and then opens the devices sequentially and crashes out.

Comment: If the Suite and Tests are run parallel at test or class level it opens one "Main" thread and runs every test sequentially on the devices.  If it's run in parallel at the instance level it creates a thread "TestNG-test=(TestNGTestName)-1" and runs everything out of that sequentially.

Comment: Your base class is still working with a `NonThreadSafe` version of `protected AppiumDriver < MobileElement > driver;`. Please remove this, and directly refer call `TLDriverFactory.getTLDriver().get()` to popout the current Thread's webdriver instance. I think you can completely get rid of your `BaseTest`. Once you have cleaned up all of the above recommendations, can you please show me how your new code looks like by posting it on http://gist.github.com/ and sharing the link here ?

Comment: This is the updated TLDriver https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7e1523fe022a019f84af187fafc88304 This is the updated BaseTest. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5aa65df84098c344e9a4cd0f9dceada2  The WithInitial is necessary otherwise there is a type mismatch of ThreadLocal AppiumDriver MobileElement to AppiumDriver MobileElement.  If I use.get() there is another type mismatch when I switch on IOS and Android drivers.  I'm not sure how to implement what you're asking without type mismatches.  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/abbbe97f99e006d2ddf952cd38c764a3  Had to use .get() here for type issu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have shared so far, here's the cleaned-up and fixed code that should support your concurrency requirements.

The Driver factory class which is responsible for creation and clean-up of Appium driver instances for each and every thread, looks like below:

```java
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class TLDriverFactory {

    private static final ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver<MobileElement>> tlDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setTLDriver(BaseTest.OS platform, String server, String udid, String bundleID) throws MalformedURLException {

        System.out.println("Current Thread ID Driver Instantiation: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
        switch (platform) {
            case IOS:
                driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL(server), DesiredCapsManager.getDesiredCapabilities(BaseTest.OS.IOS, udid, bundleID));
                break;

            default:
                driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(server), DesiredCapsManager.getDesiredCapabilities(BaseTest.OS.ANDROID, udid, bundleID));
                break;
        }

        tlDriver.set(driver);
    }

    public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getTLDriver() {
        return tlDriver.get();
    }

    public static void cleanupTLDriver() {
        tlDriver.get().quit();
        tlDriver.remove();
    }
}
```

Here's how the BaseTest which I am guessing is supposed to be the base class for all tests, would look like

```java
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

public class BaseTest {

    private static final ThreadLocal<SignInPage> signInPage = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public enum OS {
        ANDROID,
        IOS
    }

    @Parameters(value = {"udid", "bundleID", "platform", "server"})
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup(String udid, String bundleID, OS platform, String server) throws Exception {
        //Set & Get ThreadLocal Driver
        TLDriverFactory.setTLDriver(platform, server, udid, bundleID);

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        SignInPage instance;
        switch (platform) {
            case IOS:
                instance = new SignInPageIOS(TLDriverFactory.getTLDriver());
                break;

            default:
                instance = new SignInPageAndroid(TLDriverFactory.getTLDriver());
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("Current Thread ID BeforeTest: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        signInPage.set(instance);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("Current Thread ID AfterTest: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        TLDriverFactory.cleanupTLDriver();
    }

    protected static SignInPage getPageForTest() {
        return signInPage.get();
    }

}
```

Here's how the constructor of your page classes would look like

```java
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class SignInPageIOS extends SignInPage {
    public SignInPageIOS(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> tlDriver) {
        super(tlDriver);
    }
}
```

Here's how a typical test case could look like

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test_SignIn extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void authenticate() {
        //Get the instance of "SignInPage" for the current thread and then work with it.
        getPageForTest().Login("Username", "Password");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works!  Although I found that my system for some reason cannot run tests in parallel.  It may have worked before but I wouldn't know until I changed computers.  This is beautifully done code now though.  Thank you very much for your help.